# What have been India's Mars mission's benefits to science?

Tags: mars, isro, mars-orbiter-mission, mars-orbiters

From Wikipedia, it seems the objective is to gain experience in Mars missions and taking some scientific observations. My question is, did ISRO scientists discover anything new from their observations?

Comment: Well, they did prove sending probe to Mars (~70mln) cost less than minor movie about space [165mln](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interstellar_(film))/[100mln](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_(film)) ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Other than taking images of Mars' moon Deimos far side (something not done in decades) not much has been attributed to MOM yet.

The key here is to remember that the the orbiter likely won't discover anything per se, but the science data it produces can be used (probably in conjunction with other data) to help us understand the history of Mars.

Here is an article you might find interesting: http://spaceflight101.com/mom/indias-mars-orbiter-mission-delivers-first-science-results-looks-at-future-challenges/